# InfoPath Formula Generate Number

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, office-365

I am creating a PO form workflow, and part of the PO form will need to have a unique number assigned to it.  Currently we have concatenated the date to one long number, i.e. 20130920152333, but we could like to be able to shorten the number, and have it increment by one each time.  If I could set it up in the following format:

**PO-######**

that would be idea.  Could someone give me an idea of how to achieve this, using InfoPath's formula?  I can't seem to find a solid source to explain how it works, and how it needs to be built.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the built in ID the list or library is going to generate for you than trying to create your own. You'll no doubtedly run into duplicate IDs if multiple people are filling out the form at the same time.

Then with that ID, you can then do anything to display it in views in the list/library or in InfoPath, like PO-000001.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  Would this be able to display inside the InfoPath form like that, or would it just be in the list view?

Comment: It wouldn't be available when they are creating the request, but it would be available for viewing and editing when in the InfoPath form.

Comment: How would I be able to format the ID column to look that way?  I can't seem to find a way to get to edit that ID field?